# How the inability to modify the title of javascript alert() function helps in anti-phishing

Tags: web-application, javascript, phishing

I was using javascript in one of my web apps and wanted to display an alert on the screen using the function `alert("some message")` with a custom title.

example:

[image]

but as suggested by many websites, it is not possible since it is a security/anti-phishing feature of js.

Can somebody please explain, how the above mentioned feature contributes towards security (anti-phishing) in the web app?

Comment: Maybe because so that you can't trick the user into believing that the message comes from some another site, or from OS. Currently, the title shows the source of the web page.If you really really want to change the title, there're some jQuery hacks which might prove useful to you. Check this: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: It (mostly) doesn't.

The real reason why you can't modify the title is that there is no title in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#dom-alert). An alert is meant to display a simple message, not to create a complex new window.

If there would be a title parameter, it would not have any impact on security if you were able to change it. An alert is a very weak element for phishing attacks, as it can only display a simple text message (you can't even insert clickable links, so you would need to tell a user to copy-paste a link - except that copying is disabled in some browsers). Apart from being very limited, there is no reason to believe that a user would have more trust in an alert box than in a website regarding phishing attacks.

The impression that it may have an effect on security may come from the fact that browsers decide to include the originating website in the title. So an attacker may for example host JavaScript on their server that displays an alert with the title "google.com says: [...]". But I don't see a real danger here. There is no possibility to enter data in an alert. And even if there were, a user who trusts the alert would likely trust a simple phishing site without an alert as well.

As an alert is part of the browser ui, not the website ui, customization of the look and feel of an alert may provide a danger of impersonating the browser, not another webpage. So an attacker may set the title to "Important security notice" and the message to a description to copy-paste a given URL to install a "security patch". As the alert seems to originate from the browser itself, a user may follow it. But even that seems rather far-fetched to me (and being able to edit the title of a message seems a minor point here; such a user may be just as easily fooled by a message displayed inside a website itself, which has a lot more possibilities to style a message and to receive data entered by a user).